# Postgres stops using a (btree_gin) index when select clause includes a column not part of the index

Tags: postgresql, index, execution-plan, postgresql-9.6

I am seeing some strange behavior with the btree_gin extension

I have the following table

```
create table my_table(id INTEGER, a TEXT, b text);

CREATE EXTENSION btree_gin;

CREATE INDEX idx ON my_table USING gin (id, a);
```

If I run the query :

```
select t.id, t.a 
from my_table t 
where t.id = :someNumber and t.a like 'someString'
```

the index gets used.

If I add another column in the select clause that is not part of the index, the index is no longer used, ex:

```
select t.id, t.a, t.b 
from my_table t 
where t.id = :someNumber and t.a like 'someString'
```

I'm using **PostgreSQL 9.6.3**

One thing that is very strange, is that the index *does* get used if I join the table to anotherone, and add a col from the other table in the select, ex:

```
select t.id, o.a_col_from_other_table
from my_table t 
join another_table o on t.id = o.the_fk
where t.id = :someNumber and t.a like 'someString'
```

However, if the join clause uses a column not part of the index, it will will resort to seq scan.

### Update 1

For some reason, the query optimizer does not even use the btree_gin anymore. The only way I can get it to use the (btree_gin) index is with

**SET enable_seqscan = OFF;**. It turns out that even by using this index, it is quite slow, so the optimizer is probably correct in not using it, but the question is then why is it slow ?   I've used indexes for like query and they work fine, in this case there is not even a wild card.

the real query is :

```
 EXPLAIN
    SELECT
      b.transcript_translation_accession
    FROM r_prot_search b
    WHERE
        b.transcript_translation_accession like 'IP_304743.1'
        and b.assembly_id = 12  
        and b.openprot_release_id = 28
    limit 30;
```

The index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_r_prot_search2_transcript_translation_accession3 
ON r_prot_search USING gin (openprot_release_id, transcript_translation_accession);
```

and the plan :

```
"QUERY PLAN"
"Limit  (cost=27633.94..593461.27 rows=30 width=13)"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on r_prot_search b  (cost=27633.94..2366386.90 rows=124 width=13)"
"        Recheck Cond: (openprot_release_id = 28)"
"        Filter: (((transcript_translation_accession)::text ~~ 'IP_304743.1'::text) AND (assembly_id = 12))"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_r_prot_search2_transcript_translation_accession3  (cost=0.00..27633.91 rows=3079721 width=0)"
"              Index Cond: (openprot_release_id = 28)"
```

I should probably add that the query returns 5 rows, and the table has 10 millions rows.

### update 2

Here's an EXPLAIN ANALYZE, with SET enable_seqscan = ON:

```
"QUERY PLAN"
"Limit  (cost=1000.00..537006.24 rows=30 width=13) (actual time=15164.523..15610.792 rows=6 loops=1)"
"  ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..2216492.44 rows=124 width=13) (actual time=15164.521..15610.788 rows=6 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 4"
"        Workers Launched: 4"
"        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on r_prot_search b  (cost=0.00..2215480.04 rows=31 width=13) (actual time=15514.285..15603.515 rows=1 loops=5)"
"              Filter: (((transcript_translation_accession)::text ~~ 'IP_304743.1'::text) AND (assembly_id = 12) AND (openprot_release_id = 28))"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 1948958"
"Planning time: 0.370 ms"
"Execution time: 15628.514 ms"
```

Now with SET enable_seqscan = OFF;

```
"QUERY PLAN"
"Limit  (cost=27633.94..593461.27 rows=30 width=13) (actual time=3406.041..8350.549 rows=6 loops=1)"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on r_prot_search b  (cost=27633.94..2366386.90 rows=124 width=13) (actual time=3406.038..8350.544 rows=6 loops=1)"
"        Recheck Cond: (openprot_release_id = 28)"
"        Filter: (((transcript_translation_accession)::text ~~ 'IP_304743.1'::text) AND (assembly_id = 12))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 3228843"
"        Heap Blocks: exact=320353"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_r_prot_search2_transcript_translation_accession3  (cost=0.00..27633.91 rows=3079721 width=0) (actual time=640.817..640.817 rows=3228849 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (openprot_release_id = 28)"
"Planning time: 0.394 ms"
"Execution time: 8350.618 ms"
```

Comment: Can you paste the plan's with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

Comment: If this was a SQL Server query, I'd guess that the first plan was preferred because it could go parallel (so that, even if the total cumulative cost was higher, the results might be determined more quickly because multiple threads were looking. Not sure if that applies here....

Answer (score 1):

**As jjanes points out, I may not be right here if you've only got a GIN index. I'm waiting for the plan before I revise**

I don't believe the index "is no longer used" is correct. In the first query, you're selecting **ONLY** the columns indexed. That means you can potentially use an *"index-only scan"*. In the second query, you're selecting columns not in the index. That means you **CAN NOT** use an "index-only scan". That means you have to visit the table on disk.

On the basis of that, in the second case, whether or not the index is used is dependent on the selectivity estimates. We would need the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of the two queries to further assist in that. We have two options:

1. I imagine the index is used, however the rows need to be retrieved from disk and thus it is slower than the first query. This is what is likely happening.
2. PostgreSQL assess a higher cost to visiting the table **AND** the index, so it just visits the table and does a seq scan. Usually this only happens on small tables.

Comment: Gin indexes don't support index-only scans.

Comment: @jjanes good catch, I'll update if we ever get a plan. At this point, it wouldn't surprise me if he had a btree on it too.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated question is a totally different question than the original.

It seems like the answer to your original question is that in the process of adding a column to a select list, you also changed a `=` to a `like` in the where clause and you didn't realize that you did it.

To answer your updated question, `btree_gin` has never supported the `like` operator.  Real btree indexes do, but btree_gin do not.  Using `like` with btree_gin will simply not be considered, so it never gets to the point of wondering if there is a wildcard or not.  When you saw it use an index for `like`, perhaps you were seeing it use a real btree index, or perhaps you were seeing it use `pg_trgm` GIN indexes, which do support `like`, even when the search term is not left-anchored.  But when the search term has no wildcards at all, a pg_trgm index will still be "useful", but far less efficient than a simple btree index.